# IE lose custom tag while sethtml

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, ckeditor, custom-tag

**This following Code Running in FF & IE**

```
TempNode= CKEDITOR.dom.element.createFromHtml("<span></span>");
TempNode.setHtml("<p>test</p>");
```

**But below mentioned code losing user defined Tags In IE (FF Works Fine)**

```
TempNode= CKEDITOR.dom.element.createFromHtml("<span></span>");
TempNode.setHtml("<myTag>test</myTag>");
```

**Also same problem with **appendHtml()****

**My Exact Requirement is :**

```
 Element.setHtml(AnotherElement.getHtml());
```

**original value in AnotherElement.getHtml() is:**

```
<P><mytag id="test_39878" data-cke-expando="undefined">some. text</myTag></P>
```

**after Element.sethtml() it containing value is :**

```
<P>some. tex</MYTAG></P>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use your own tags in IE you've got to create them first. This is the same situation that we've got with HTML5 tags.

So before setting HTML with `<myTag>`, create it `CKEDITOR.document.createElement( 'mytag' )` just to let IE know it exists.

BTW. Remember that elements must be created in the same document in which they'll be used. So if you want to insert them into editor's content, then create them in editor's document (e.g. `CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.document`). Otherwise IE will throw an error.

Comment: <myTag> is already exist in document content but it throwing error

Comment: please see the edited post. its not giving error but some value automatically losing

Comment: As I told you - create elements for your tags (this has to be done before using them) and everything should work.

Comment: i setting HTML with `CKEDITOR.document.createElement('myTag');` and also i tried with
`EditorInstance.document.createElement("myTag");`  but still same result please check once again my problem. thank you