# Dummy(Duplicate) Node in Ckeditor [IE]

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, duplicates, ckeditor

in CKEDITOR Document I have a node named **User_Image**

```
<User_Image><sometags><sometags>sometext<sometags>sometext</sometags></sometags></sometags></User_Image>
```

User_Image node i stored in Variable Uimage

```
var Duimage=CKEDITOR.dom.element.createFromHtml(Uimage.getOuterHtml());
```

now just i created (dummy) duplicate node but this code supported me in all browsers other than IE.
in IE Missing Customtags. the all tags are dynamic.

then i try with following :

```
var Duimage=ediInstance.document.createElement("User_Image");
 Uimage.appendTo(Duimage);
```

but in this code if i changed in Duimage it also affect in CKEDITOR Document

any other Idea to get Duplicate Node ?

Comment: Please see this post also @Reinmar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all - check my answer here [IE lose custom tag while sethtml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12967695/ie-browser-losing-ckeditor-element-sethtmluserdefinedtags-userdefinedtags/12969485#12969485)

Second - after you add support for custom tag in IE (remember to do this in the document in which element will be used) you can use element's `clone()` method. Here's its doc: http://nightly-v4.ckeditor.com/ckeditor_api/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dom.node-method-clone