# CKEDITOR losing custom nodes while getElementsByTag on IE

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor, nodes

ckeditor  losing custom tags while getElementsByTag on IE

in Document Content as below :

```
 <initTag id="ss">
  <myTag id="aa1">text</myTag>
  <myTag id="ab2">Text</myTag>
  <otherTag id="aac">
    <myTag id="ab3">text</myTag>
  </otherTag>
</initTag>
```

`<initTag>` is in (variable) itag

```
var nNode = itag.getElementsByTag("myTag"); 
for(var x; x<nNode.count();x++){
alert(nNode.getItem(x).getOuterHtml());
}
```

alert message as follow :

(other than newly added )which one is Already  in document  :

```
<MYTAG id="AB3">
```

just before added tags Only like as :

```
<myTag id="ab2">Text</myTag>
```

**how can i get all nodes properly?**

PLEASE Also check following code :

```
<head runat="server">
       <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        function btnclick() {
            var testctrl = document.createElement("myTag");
            testctrl.innerHTML = "test Val";
           var tt= document.getElementById("temp");
          tt.appendChild(testctrl);
            var testnd = document.getElementsByTagName("myTag");
          for (var i = 0; i < testnd.length; i++) {

              alert(testnd.item(i).outerHTML);
          }

        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="temp" >
    </div>
    <input type="button" id="tbtn" onclick="javascript:btnclick();return false;" value="ClickMe"/>
  <myTag>1</myTag>
    <myTag>2</myTag>
    <myTag>3</myTag>
    <myTag>4</myTag>
    <myTag>5</myTag>
    <myTag>6</myTag>
    <myTag>7</myTag>
    <myTag>8</myTag>
    <myTag>9</myTag>
    <myTag>0</myTag>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see folowing Link:

http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/

This link can be solve html5 tag problems and also you can add your own tags into this js file.
may be this is your requirement.

You should add your customTags on Html5shiv.js as below :

```
if (html5.shivCSS && !supportsHtml5Styles && !data.hasCSS) {
      data.hasCSS = !!addStyleSheet(ownerDocument,
        // corrects block display not defined in IE6/7/8/9
        'myTag,article,aside,figcaption,figure,footer,header,hgroup,nav,section{display:block}' +
        // adds styling not present in IE6/7/8/9
        'mark{background:#FF0;color:#000}'
      );
```

And here :

var html5 = {

```
       'elements': options.elements || 'myTag abbr article aside audio bdi canvas data datalist details figcaption figure footer header hgroup mark meter nav output progress section summary time video',
```

This Answer May be Solve your Some other Questions

Comment: @Reinmar, please see this Answer and if you Accept this Vote for me

Answer (score 3):

It's not CKEditor losing this nodes. You have to add support for them in IE.

See my other answers on similar questions:

- [IE lose custom tag while sethtml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12967695/ie-browser-losing-ckeditor-element-sethtmluserdefinedtags-userdefinedtags/12969485#12969485)
- [Dummy(Duplicate) Node in Ckeditor [IE]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13023608/dummyduplicate-node-in-ckeditor-ie/13029566#13029566)

Comment: Thats ok but i already have custom tags in document.when i use `Editor.document.createElement("myTag");` then i call `Parent.getElementsByTag("myTag");` new elements on node properly As `<myTag>value</myTag>` old elements are in node as `<myTag>`. there is no inner content and End Tag. How can i get all nodes with inner Content?

Comment: Much probably you're creating these elements to late. It has to be done before they are first used. Check these two jsfiddles: http://jsfiddle.net/Ah769/ http://jsfiddle.net/Ah769/5/. First is your example - we see incorrect behaviour. Second is fixed sample in which I call `createElement` before IE parses body element.

Comment: for html is working but not working on ckeditor. if possible to Editor.document.createElement in ckeditor.js otherwise can we create extra plugin for userdefined tag?. which one is possible