# CKEditor "insertHtml" is working for FF but not working for IE8

Tags: javascript, asp.net, firefox, internet-explorer-8, ckeditor

I want to append a new HTML tag in ckeditor content. 
bellow code is working fine for FF but its not inserting the tag in IE8.

`setData()` will not work for me. I think it's replacing all content with the new HTML tag.

```
var idVal = 123; 
var attrib2Val = "some value";
var NewHtmlTag = "<CustTag id=\"c" + idVal + "\" attrib2=\"" + attrib2Val + "\"></CustTag> some extra text ";

EditorInstance.insertHtml(NewHtmlTag);
```

I need a solution for IE8+.

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [IE Browser losing ckeditor element setHtml("<userdefinedTags></userdefinedTags>")](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12967695/ie-browser-losing-ckeditor-element-sethtmluserdefinedtags-userdefinedtags)

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you're trying to insert element with custom tag name (non standard). Check my answer for similar question [IE lose custom tag while sethtml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12967695/ie-browser-losing-ckeditor-element-sethtmluserdefinedtags-userdefinedtags/12969485#12969485)

If this isn't a case, then, please, give us more details about the content of `NewHtmlTag` value. What is it?

Comment: thanks for reply. yes i am trying to insert/append a custom tag and as per your link i've used CKEDITOR.document.createElement( 'mytag' ) but its not working for me. bellow code i want to implement which having the details of NewHtmlTag also.                                                 

var idVal = 123;
var attrib2Val = "some value";

var NewHtmlTag = "<CustTag id=\"c" + idVal + "\" attrib2=\"" + attrib2Val + "\"></CustTag> some text ";
EditorInstance.insertHtml(NewHtmlTag);

Comment: Could you update your original question with entire code that you've written? With that `createElement( 'mytag' )` so I can verify how you really do this.

Comment: So... why do you create `MCTag` when you're inserting `CustTag`? It has to be the same name. You "initialize" it.